# Single Sign-On on UWP app using Microsoft account not working as expected

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, single-sign-on

I am experiencing a scenario where our UWP App user must type their password in all the time when they login (using their Microsoft account).

**- Expectation**

User logs in to our UWP App with their Microsoft account username & password (e.g. mrBigglesworth@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com). The normal ‘Stay signed in?’ dialog is displayed with ‘Don’t show this again’ checkbox. The user selects ‘Yes’ on this dialog. Subsequent logins to the App by the same user do not show the login screens. Effectively, this creates a Single Sign-On experience.

This is how our App worked prior to the April 2018 update to Windows 10 with the existing code (see below). As far as I can tell, this is the update that made things not work.

**- What is happening**

The ‘Stay signed in?’ dialog is not displayed – at all. So, the user must provide the password every time. Even if I clear the cookies, cache, and sign in with a new user (not used before), or uninstall the App, I still must provide the password – every time. We are not using ADFS, but this was the case in the past too when things ‘worked’.

Our UWP App is a hosted Web App that takes the users to our existing Web Portal. When I use a browser, clear the cache and then sign in again, everything works as expected and I do see the 'Stay signed in?' dialog. So, it is the UWP functionality that is missing something.

**- What has been done**

Our UWP App uses a WebView control to display our Web Portal. I have a ‘Logout user’ functionality which deletes all cookies for known domains (see list below) and clears the WebView cache. The domain name list was compiled with the aid of Fiddler tool to monitor **all** URL/traffic when logging in to our Web Portal. This code used to work as expected before (i.e. user sign out and logging in again produced the ‘Stay signed in?’ dialog). I have tried uninstalling the App too but no joy (using right-click uninstall as wee as the Azure PowerShell script - "Get-AppxPackage | ? {$_.IsDevelopmentMode -eq "True"} | Remove-AppxPackage").

C# code snippet for deleting cookie and clearing WebView cache is below (some business-specific strings have been changed to protect the innocent).

```
private static readonly string[] AllCookieDomains = {
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "https://login.mydomain.com",
    "https://mydomain-us.azurewebsites.net",
    "https://mydomaingraph-us.azurewebsites.net",
    "https://mydomainlogin.azurewebsites.net",
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "https://mydomainapps.azurewebsites.net",
    "https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com",
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login",
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize"
};

foreach (string domainName in AllCookieDomains)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domainName))
    {
        Uri aUri = new Uri(domainName);

        foreach (var cookie in baseFilter.CookieManager.GetCookies(aUri))
        {
            baseFilter.CookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}

await WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync();
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.ClearAuthenticationCache();
```

I may have checked the ‘Don’t show this again’ box on the ‘Stay signed in?’ dialog. It should not matter if I delete the cookies/uninstall the App, but if it is applicable, how does one reset it?

Any assistance/help will be greatly appreciated.

**Additional information:**

If you are asking about my WebView code, then the excerpt from my MainPage is:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainViewGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <WebView x:Name="MainWebView" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.WebViewSource, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="4,0,4,4"
                 NavigationStarting="MainWebView_NavigationStarting" NavigationCompleted="MainWebView_NavigationCompleted"
                 NewWindowRequested="MainWebView_NewWindowRequested" DefaultBackgroundColor="White"
                 ContainsFullScreenElementChanged="MainWebView_ContainsFullScreenElementChanged" RightTapped="MainWebView_RightTapped"
                 UnviewableContentIdentified="MainWebView_UnviewableContentIdentified" DOMContentLoaded="MainWebView_DOMContentLoaded">
        </WebView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

View Model
    WebViewSource = new Uri(SkoolerResources.SkoolerLoginUrl_Metadata);
    // First URL for our App is 'https://login.skooler.com/common/Metadata'.

This then redirects to login.microsoftonline.com (as the user is not authorised).

Please note that it all works as expected when I use our portal using a browser. So some login info within WebView is being retained or not - which is causing the SSO issue.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried to use webview control to load website that contain Micrsoft Login module. And it works, even if reload the page. Could your show more about our Web Portal?

Comment: Hi Nico. Thanks for your comment. When you say 'it works', do you mean you can successfully login? I can as well. The issue is that I don't see the 'Stay signed in?' dialog AFTER logging in to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'. This, I believe, is making the SSO not work.

Comment: @'Nico Zhu - MSFT' - I have added additional information to my post.

Comment: Do you test web portal within browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing browser cookies should reset the state and clear out the "Don't show this again" setting.

Some reasons why the "Stay signed in" dialog won't show include:

1. Different account was previously used in the browser (this state is also
   removed by clearing cookies as mentioned above)
2. Some form of SSO set up in the browser
3. Loaded in a hosted webview

If the above doesn't resolve this issue for you, please send me a fiddler trace of a login where the "Stay signed in" dialog doesn't show up and I can look into why it was suppressed.

Comment: Hi. I am mainly interested in SSO experience for my users. I.e. user should not get the enter credentials/password dialog. This was working fine in the past - user logs in first time after App installation; subsequent launch of App would take them directly to our Main landing page. Now, it keeps displaying the credentials/password dialog. IMHO, this is somehow related to the 'Stay signed in?' dialog because this is the only difference I see when accessing our portal through a normal browser & accessing the same through WebView within UWP App. I will try to get the fiddler trace.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. As requested, I have gathered session trace from Fiddler. Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JiiocKK8H-tfKVobvtKh-rLhaCudp-e5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For comparison, I have also loaded a trace for the Browser access to Web App. The Web App is behaving as expected (when I clear the browser cache, I get the Stay Signed In dialog). Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VUMjpMMBbhptrUOnOMUhuDWMlStLTMUj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Wondering if someone has had the time to look into this and provide any information. Or if there is anything I need to do. Thank you.